# Zoho CRM API to Power BI Connector

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, powerquery, zoho, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to connect to Zoho CRM API to import data into PowerBI and I am receiving an error after logging into Zoho through my custom connector, I hope you can help as my connector seems 90% complete, just missing the final step! (code below).

Error message: [DataFormatError] We couldn't parse your query string as it was improperly formatted

```
// This file contains your Data Connector logic
section Zoho_Connector___V1.1;

// TODO: add your client id and secret to the embedded files

client_id = "XXXXX";

client_secret = "XXXXXX";

redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html";

windowWidth = 800;

windowHeight = 800;

//Oauth base url for

OAuthBaseUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/auth?";


[DataSource.Kind="Zoho_Connector___V1.1", Publish="Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Publish"]
shared Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Contents = () =>
let

navTable = Web.Contents("https://www.zohoapis.eu/crm/v2/Leads")

in

navTable;


// Data Source Kind description
Zoho_Connector___V1.1 = [
Authentication = [
// enable both OAuth and Key based auth

OAuth = [

StartLogin = StartLogin,

FinishLogin = FinishLogin,

Refresh=Refresh

]

],
Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];

// Data Source UI publishing description
Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Publish = [
Beta = true,
Category = "Other",
ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
SourceImage = Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Icons,
SourceTypeImage = Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Icons
];

// OAuth2 flow definition

//


// Start Login thorugh OAUTH
StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>

let

AuthorizeUrl = OAuthBaseUrl & Uri.BuildQueryString([

scope = "ZohoCRM.modules.all",

client_id = client_id,

redirect_uri = redirect_uri,

response_type = "code",

state = state,

access_type = "online"])

in

[

LoginUri = AuthorizeUrl,

CallbackUri = redirect_uri,

WindowHeight = windowHeight,

WindowWidth = windowWidth,

Context = null

];

// Finish Login through OAUTH

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>

let

Parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query]

in

TokenMethod(Parts[code], "authorization_code");



TokenMethod = (code, grant_type) =>

let

Response = Web.Contents(OAuthBaseUrl & "/token", [

Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString([

grant_type = "authorization_code",

client_id = client_id,

client_secret = client_secret,

redirect_uri = redirect_uri,

code = code
]
)),

Headers=[#"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"Accept" = "application/json"]]),

Parts = Json.Document(Response)

in

Parts;



Refresh = (resourceUrl, refresh_token) => TokenMethod(refresh_token, "refresh_token");

Zoho_Connector___V1.1.Icons = [
Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.116.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.120.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.124.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.132.png") },
Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.132.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.140.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.148.png"), Extension.Contents("Zoho_Connector___V1.164.png") }
];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Dear Alex, are you able to make some progress?

Answer (score 0):

YOu have bug in your code (probably there is more )
please take a look on this variable

```
OAuthBaseUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/auth?";
```

your exchange code url is

```
OAuthBaseUrl & "/token"
```

please focus on a question mark at the end of OauthBaseUrl
it will resolve to this

```
https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/auth?/token
```

but it should

```
https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/token
```

My other suggestion is to add error handling and logs to your code. It will help you to exactly understand problem. You can also get response headers and status to be sure about potential problem